# set environment variables within a mountPath in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mount

we have deployed an application in Kubernetes as deployment and stored the logs in a folder named /podlogs. whenever the pod has taken the restart, it will create a new folder named with the latest pod name inside the app-log folder and store the actual log files.  For example this new folder could be /podlogs/POD_Name

Previously we have mounted /podlogs to ELK and azure blob containers.

By using the subPath, we would like to also mount the /podlogs/POD_Name to a second mount.

How can we pass the env variable in the mount path along with the subPath?

Comment: First, post text as text not as images. Second, clarify the question. I have no idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you set your container to log to stdout instead?  Logstash should be able to collect the Kubernetes container logs, and this would let you get rid of this volume mount entirely.

Comment: hello @David, via file-beat integration we are fetching the logs to elastic search. Due to a few constraints, don't have a chance to set a longer retention period there. So, Would like to set the mount on the same folder to azure blob container

Answer (score 0):

See the DownwardAPI https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

It is possible to expose the pod name as a env variable or to mount

It is conceivable you could then mount or expose this to the ELK container